# When read or write to redux, the page is re rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use this piece of code to change a value in redux, every time that I call the action "send message" the form is re rendered and the console log "Page mounted" is repeated, why?

```js
function Fake() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Page mounted");
  }, []);

  const changeDataInStore = ({ msg }: { msg: string }) => {
    sendMessage(msg);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => changeDataInStore({ msg: "test" })}>
        <label>Change data</label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default memo(Fake);
```

Answer (score 3):

Is any ancestor of `Fake` (whichever component calls `Fake` or the parent of the component calling `Fake` and so on...) subscribed to the redux state that `sendMessage` updates? That would do it.